# How to create a compiled, redistributable class library in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, class-library

Is it possible to create a small library (similar to a Flash or Flex SWC component) that can be used in Silverlight apps?

Since I'm a Flash and Flex developer, I'll relate it. In Flex, if I have a SWC I can add it to my build path and then immediately use its included classes and functions in my project. Similarly, in Flash if I add a SWC to the Components folder then drag that SWC into my library, I can use the classes in my Flash project.

Does Silverlight have a similar concept? I just need a small code library that I can send to other developers, but it should be pre-compiled so the source is not readily available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not have an issue pre-compiling the "Silverlight Class Library" project type in Visual Studio like you would traditional C# libraries, and release these to developers who can reference them in their Silverlight applications.

Comment: It will be a dll that you can add to your silverlight project.

Comment: I would vote this left if I could vote more today.  You may want to.